# Drag and drop jquery, подскажите пожалуйста как работать с изменением размера текста или картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

когда я вызываю функцию resizable

```
function resizeid(){
    $('#'+idselected).resizable({
        disabled: false
    });

}
```

для тега img он оборачивает его в div и то коряво, потом когда выключаю

```
function resizeoffid(){
    console.log(idselected);
    $('.ui-wrapper').resizable({
     disabled: true   
    });


}
```

созданная обертка не исчезает

также работает и с текстом. С блоками эта функция работает хорошо

Comment: `$('.ui-wrapper').each(function(){ this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML; });` — можно дописать в функцию. Хотя не факт, что disabled: true вообще нужно (не знаком), если оно всё равно будет удаляться.

Comment: Может есть какой-то другой способ работы с масштабированием img или h1-h3, p и другой текст ?

Comment: действительно  disabled: true    уже не нужен вот дополнил код если вдруг кому нужно будет

$('.ui-wrapper').each(function(){ this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML; });
 $('.ui-resizable-handle').each(function(){ this.outerHTML = this.innerHTML; });

Comment: тут получается такая штука, когда удаляешь эту обертку то при повторном включении управление размером то уже не включается